# Sending email with attachments through iOS Outlook

Tags: ios, objective-c, outlook, ms-word

My application (a DMS client) has strong ties to Microsoft technology, so my customers are on average much more likely to run *Outlook for iOS* than the default iOS *Mail* client.

However, Outlook does not respond to the `MFMailComposeViewController`, so that basically leaves two approaches on the table for sending email from the app:

1. Use the `msoutlook://` URL scheme to open Outlook. This supports pre-populating  recipients, subject, and a HTML styled body text, apparently without a maximum length. **However, it does not seem to support attachments**.
2. Use the `UIActivityViewController` (i.e. the "sharing" interface), which does allow for attachments (hurray!), but I don't know if it's possible to pre-populate any of the fields other than the content...and the sharing dialog itself is really unpleasant UI, interrupting the user flow with a complex choice.

Word (for iOS) presents the user with the following flow that *directly* opens a document as an attachment to a new email in Outlook. Assuming they don't use any private APIs, how are they doing that?

[image: In Word, select Send a Copy]
[image: Select option Email with Outlook]
[image: Outlook appears with Word document attached]

Comment: Given that both Word and Outlook are from Microsoft, they are probably sharing a file using an application group; unfortunately this route isn't available to you.